# Simple EditText in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I want to make an edit text in fragment of my view pager(slider). Here what i have done already in my DetailFragment2.java:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

LayoutInflater inflater2 = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
aView = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.details2, null);
EditText notatki = (EditText) aView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

//notatki = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText1);
SharedPreferences settings = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
notatki.setText(settings.getString("value", "raz dwa trzy"));
return notatki;      
}
```

and in details2.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

And i cant still see any of edittext field in that view. What am i doing wrong?

I changed it in that way and it works, thanks for help:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details2, container, false);
EditText notatki = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
SharedPreferences settings = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
notatki.setText(settings.getString("value", "raz dwa trzy"));
return view;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Edit Text is there but you just set transparent background so you can't see it.

```
android:background="#00000000"
```

you have 4 pairs of zeroes so the format is **AARRGGBB** the first **AA** - zeroes in your case - sets the `alpha = 0` so the background is fully transparent.

try to set background to #RR0000 or just use **RRGGBB** format (#000000)

**EDIT**
since above didn't resolve the problem try to update the way you inflate your layout

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

aView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details2, parent, false);
EditText notatki = (EditText) aView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

//notatki = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText1);
SharedPreferences settings = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
notatki.setText(settings.getString("value", "raz dwa trzy"));
return notatki;      
}
```

the following two lines are the most important:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

and

```
aView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details2, parent, false);
```

Comment: No, it is not there. I try to make it as u said, but still I can't see anything